# Photoshop: batch resizing for web

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to take a group of 65K images and downsample it so that it is around 10K.
Can someone tell me what I need to know to do this?  I am not as concerned right now about each file being the same filesize, but if anyone has recommendations for that I am all ears.  It seems like color profile settings get in the way of uniformity.

I tried the `'save for web & devices'`, but it doesn't seem to work.
I try:

1. add new action in actions panel / start recording on action
2. change default colorspace to monitor spec
3. save for web and devices - 800 height max, 50 - 100% quality
4. hit save and choose destination
5. batch- open images only with folder destination specified seems to override the default location

this only seems to work sometimes and i can't figure out why.
i should also be able to use

EDIT: FWIW, I am on Mac ONLY.

Thanks for any help,

jml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done any batch processing in Photoshop in a while, so I can't comment. What I want to share is that if for some reason you aren't able to do what you need via batch processing, Photoshop can also be scripted via AppleScript, VBScript, and Javascript.

[Here's](http://www.kirupa.com/motiongraphics/ps_scripting.htm) an article about Photoshop scripting. [Here's](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting/) Adobe's current documentation. If you need older docs, you'll need to google for them.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be using photoshop? [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) has nice powerful batch processing capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't helpful (*Why are you writing the answer then ?*), but such things weren't, for a fact, available in older verions of photoshop (around 4). I don't know about the newer ones, but I usually gave up on photoshop, and started using [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) tools for anything remotely similar. Install them once, you won't be using them *too often*, but every once in a while, something like this will pop up, and then, they'll be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

[XnViewMP for MacOS X](http://www.xnview.com/en/downloadunix.html) does batch convert.

Comment: Thanks for all of these references.  Very useful...  But I'm not on Windows. :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why wouldn't you recommend batch resizing in PS?  Is it broken?

Comment: XnView for Mac OS X: http://www.xnview.com/en/downloadunix.html

Comment: @Molly: Thanks - I've considerably shortened my answer now.

Comment: @jml: didn't you say you have problems with PS?

Comment: @harrymc: yes, that's correct.
I don't really understand how any of these suggestions relate to PS, but maybe this all means that I shouldn't be using it?

Comment: @jml: PS works perfectly well on the PC but I've no experience with the Mac. If you're using the latest PS version and encountering problems, you should rather get in touch with their support than ask on this forum. All I can do for you here is offer alternatives.