# How do I batch process RAW images based on EXIF data in Photoshop?

Tags: images, batch, adobe-photoshop, processing, camera-raw

I use Photoshop to batch convert my RAW files to JPG.

With my particular camera lens, if I open the aperture all the way to F1.7, there is noticeable vignetting; images where the aperture is stopped down further do not have this issue. Since the aperture information is stored in the EXIF data, what I'd like to do is have Photoshop batch process all my RAW files, and anything that is at F1.7 should automatically have vignette correction applied to it, but not on the others (applying correction to the others would over-brighten the corners of the image).

Is anything like this possible using Photoshop? They are RW2 files from a Panasonic GF1 camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to script this in Photoshop. For more info, see my answer to the following question: [Photoshop: batch resizing for web](https://superuser.com/questions/90261/photoshop-batch-resizing-for-web/90334#90334)

Comment: Yep; has to be scripted if you want to use conditional logic.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about scripting, that might work out.

Comment: It looks pretty tricky, will have to decode lots of stuff to figure it out, but seems like my best bet

Answer (score 2):

To answer your last question:

> Should I use some other RAW processing
> tool instead?

[Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) has a [Windows build](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) and is very, very scriptable. It generally reads everything, but it may not read that particular flavor of RAW files. [DCRAW](http://www.cybercom.net/%7Edcoffin/dcraw/) is the first Linux tool I thought of that decodes RAW files; there are third-party Windows builds (and that page links to a lot of Windows tools that handle RAW; ironically, Photoshop is one of them.)

Hope this helps. Imagemagick was built to be scriptable (at least on Linux) so it's probably going to be slightly easier than figuring out a javascript API.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using? It's probably possible to do what you want with an external scripting tool, such as AppleScript, but that's obviously OS-dependent.

Comment: Windows. Photoshop supports JavaScript scripting on both Mac and Windwos, according to the other guy that posted. It's not real easy, and it looks like I have to decipher lots of obscure commands to make it work, but it might be possible.